# Fix a footer to the bottom only when scrolled to the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I would like to fix my footer to the bottom of the browser window, but only in the situation where the user is already at the very bottom of the page.

If you noticed on iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks/Yosemite in Safari, when you scroll past the page limit more content is displayed to obtain that elastic bounce back effect. This looks really fantastic when you have a fixed header, it just displays more of the background above the top of your page while the header is completely fixed, just like on native apps.

But when you have a footer that's not fixed to the bottom - they have to scroll down the page to see the footer, when the user scrolls to the bottom and then scrolls past that limit, more of the background color will appear underneath the footer which looks quite bad. Therefore, if I am able to fix the footer when that occurs, it would behave exactly like the always-fixed header in regards to scrolling past the page limit.

This is what I want to change - notice white appears underneath the footer after scrolling past the end of the page. If the footer is fixed to the bottom this won't occur and instead the whitespace will be added above the footer.

[image: demonstration]

This is what I want to obtain - notice more yellow is added above the footer not below it. I want just that but I don't want to have the footer always fixed - it should be positioned statically so that it's not visible until they scroll to the bottom, then once it's at the bottom it should become fixed to obtain the desired page limit scroll behavior. Of course scrolling back up should position it statically again.

[JSBin Code](http://jsbin.com/diwezoroxi)
[image]

Is this a job for `position:sticky`? I'd prefer a CSS-only solution over JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: You will need JavaScript/jQuery in order to do this, you will need a script to add and remove classes depending on how much the user scrolled down in order to accomplish this effect

Comment: `position: sticky` would be awesome to work with, [but it has basically no browser support worth speaking of](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) :(

Comment: @misterManSam Considering Safari is the only browser with this behavior, and `position:sticky` is supported in Safari (`-webkit`), that's just fine and I'd prefer to use it if that can be used to get the desired behavior. I've only seen it used for sticking a header for sections at the top.

Comment: Awesome! So if I understand correctly... you want something [like this example?](http://jsbin.com/fuxuhatevo/1)

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam! Unfortunately that still behaves as if the `position` wasn't changed. I'll post a gif - notice there's white underneath the black footer when I would like to change that so you never see white underneath it and instead more white is added above the footer.

Comment: @misterManSam You're running an older version of Safari, pre 7.1 then. Notice the gray background appears underneath the page. That was changed very recently to instead show more web page content instead of Safari's UI underneath the page.

Comment: @Joey - Yeah! Ok, I see. Now... That seems unlikely to be possible without disabling the browser snapback (maybe with a vendor CSS property) and then replicating the snapback with jQuery... We just don't have the control.

Comment: @Joey  - orrrr capturing the scroll before it causes the snapback affect and then making your own to compensate... All roads lead to javascript I'm afraid.

Comment: @misterManSam Mimicking the built in snapback is evil. :P It should be possible, and it works really well if I `position:fixed; bottom:0;` the footer (http://jsbin.com/diwezoroxi). But I don't always want it to be fixed, only when the user is scrolled to or past the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Joey - :p - it works with fixed because all it cares about is the viewport. It seems that sticky elements have different behaviour. You can easily make it change to `position: fixed` when it gets to a certain point in the scroll with jQuery. Best bet IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work...!! Good Luck !!

```
#footer {
position:fixed;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:30px;
width:100%;
background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html 

#footer 
{
position:absolute;
top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Comment: This seems to place the footer at the bottom of the browser window statically so it covers up the body content then upon scrolling it doesn't move so the footer doesn't lie at the bottom of the page. Do you have an example where this code works as desired?